# React Native Webview - undefined is not a function

Tags: android, react-native, webview, react-navigation, expo

Hello i hope someone can help me, since i have been searching in the internet for some time now without any result and i am a beginner in react.
Currently i am working on a react-native App.

The Mainscreen is nothing more than a Webview showing a Website. From the Mainscreen there is a single Button which directs me into some Settingsview.
Now the Problem is, i have overridden the Backhandler for Android by adding a Listener, so that when the Backbutton (Hardware) is clicked, the goBack function of the Webview ref is called e.g. this.mywebview.goBack().

When i start the app, this works fine, but when i go into another Screen by clicking on the Settingsbutton and from there i navigate back, it doesn't work anymore.
Now when i click the Backbutton, a Error will be shown with the message: null - undefined is not a object.

Comment: please provide some code. I presume you are getting an error simply because there is nothing to go back to once you navigate back. But without any code there is nothing anyone can do.

Answer (score 0):

You need to inject that JavaScript into your WebView.

On your WebView, ensure that you have got a function that handles the logic for going back.

```
const goBack = () => {
  // Do some logic, this is on your WebView
};
```

Then inside of your React Native app, you can simply use:

```
_goBack = () => {
  this.webView.injectJavaScript(`
    (function() {
      goBack();
    })();
  `);
  return true;
}
```

Comment: i tried but i still get that error. i think it's because if i goback from the Settings into the Webview, the former reference doesn't exist anymore. Does that make any sense?